# How to Create Customizable Reports Using Birt

Tags: birt

I have n number of columns in table. I want Generate selected columns reports dynamically. How can I do this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , as Virgil mentioned , BIRT DesignEngine API [**DEAPI**] is the best approach for any sort of runtime changes for report generation or template based report generations.

The approach involves usage of DataSource Handles ,Table Handles ,Design Element Handles .

Please refer Using DEAPI for table manipulation in this link
[ **https://dzone.com/articles/eclipses-birt-using-design**]

Edit 1 :

Also refer following link , for some quick pointers

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1074463/

Comment: Thanks arise. I have one more doubt can we delete row and columns from cross tab also?

Comment: As per the following code  , modulehandle and then on elementfactory handles are used. Just a pointer ..use removeColumnBindings(..)' */
 public static ExtendedItemHandle createCrosstabCell( ModuleHandle module )
 {
  if ( module == null )
   return null;
  return module.getElementFactory( ).newExtendedItem( null,
    CROSSTAB_CELL_EXTENSION_NAME );
 }
'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the BIRT Design Engine API to completely build a report... or use some BIRT scripting with an existing report design.  You can have most of the report built, even the datasources, and then just add columns to a table (Look for examples of BIRT Dynamic tables and columns) ... or you can build your whole dataset using scripting.  There is an example out there called ""Creating Column Dynamically" BIRT" that has a downloadable example rptdesign file

Comment: Thanks Virgil. I have one more doubt can we delete row and columns from cross tab also?

Comment: @virgil I don't see this rptdesign attached. can you refer to exact link?